# Unexpected token in Mocha/Chai

Tags: terminal, syntax-error, mocha.js

This is something I've wondered about for some time now, but only recently am I stuck on this. I am getting this error below when running my test in Mocha:

[image]

What does the `(14:58)` mean? I'm assuming it's the location of the syntax error, but how exactly do I read this in order to locate the error (for future reference)?

Thanks.

Comment: What was involved with `my test`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that node found something it couldn't handle at line 14, column 58 in core.spec.js. Note that the actual error that causes this could be located before this point if your syntax has logical errors.

Example:

```
if(foo === bar){
    console.log('foo equals bar')}
} else { // <-- Unexpected token 'else', but error is on previous line
    console.log('nope');
}
```

would trigger an error on line 3, column 3. But the actual error is the accidental extra ending curly bracket.

(But please, don't post images of code and terminal output. Text will do very well.)

Comment: Okay. Yeah, I figured the first number meant the line number. Figured out the problem, thanks.